# Multiple iOS GET Requests (Dynamic Number of Requests)

Tags: ios, xml, nsmutableurlrequest

I am using an online API to retrieve random famous quotes.  In my code, I use:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urloftheapi]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
    [connection release];
```

However, I want it to pull in possibly more than one quote.  The API doesn't include a function for multiple quotes, so I would need to run more than one `NSMutableURLRequest` to get it all.  However, since it could be 1 request, and could be several, I'm not sure the best way to implement this in code.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the API is setup you could do one request to get the list of the quotes (IE an array / dictionary of quoteID's, etc). From there you can loop through all the quoteID's you got and do a specific request to get each quote by the quotes ID property.

Without a description of the API its nearly impossible to give you an exact answer but what I just described is the general approach for these types of problems.

1) Make a request to get the list of quotes (just their primary key / unique id's)

2) Loop through all the id's from the previous request and make a specific request to get the quote by what id.

Using the AFNetworking Library it would look something like this. Keep in mind the requests are processed in a different thread so you may want to setup a NSNotification to keep track of when you finished getting each individual quote and/or keep track of the total number of quotes (the outside loop) and the current individual quote you are requesting (the inside loop). By comparing these two counts you can tell when you are finished.

```
NSMutableArray *allQuotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSString *url = @"www.whatever.com/api/quotes";
[manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSArray *quoteList = (NSArray *)responseObject;
    for(NSString *quoteID in quoteList)
    {
        [manager GET:url parameters:@{@"quoteID":quoteID} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            [allQuotes addObject:responseObject];
            [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"FINISHED_GETTING_QUOTE" object:allQuotes];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            //Handle failure here...
        }];
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //Handle failure here...
}];
```

---

```
-(void)finishedGettingQuotes:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   if(currentRequest == totalRequests)
   {
      NSMutableArray *temp = notification.object;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting the details in the OP.  The API only allows for retrieval of 1 random quote per call.  I went ahead and set up a loop to run the method over and over again, based off of some other details of the app that will set the int for number of times.  What would be best way to loop all the returned quotes together into one array or string?

Comment: I would setup a global NSMutableArray as a property. This can be done in the .h by adding "@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allQuotes" (without quotes obv). Every time the request for getting a quote has finished just append the returned NSString to that global array by doing "[allQuotes addObject:newString]"

Comment: In your sample here, how would I go about telling it how many times to loop through the request, say to get 5 random quotes?